# Can't count TreeView ChildNode after index 0

Tags: c#, .net, treeview

```
treeView2.Nodes[1].Text  = string.Format("Node's Count [{0}]", treeView1.Nodes[1].Nodes.Count);
```

Why does this code not work? The TreeView has 2 RootNodes and 5 ChildNodes. Thanks in advance!
I get the following error : 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' .

Comment: It would be helpful to point out what "does not work" means. What is the output now? What did you expect? Errors?

Comment: Thank you for the advice Jeff !